# Firefox font-face is bold in OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, fonts

Why are my fonts bold on OS X? I found the solution for Safari:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

But I did not find anything to fix Firefox. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

This fixes Chrome and Safari for Mac:

```
text-shadow: #000266 0 0 0; 
font-weight:100;
```

I tried this but it didn't work for Firefox:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Comment: Yeah, Firefox doesn't use webkit so the -webkit prefix won't work. Did you try other font-weights? e.g. 400 or 500 instead of 100?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search at Google, I found this page: [How To Fix Firefox Fonts That Turned Bold in Mac OSX](http://www.withoutink.com/apple/how-to-fix-firefox-fonts-turned-bold-mac-osx/)

Basically what it says is to delete your Lucida Grande font from your system, because it may have been corrupted.

You shouldn't have to worry, the font should be restored automatically. And if you need more explanation, just click the link. It details the process nicely.

Answer (score 1):

In my `@font-face` declaration I changed the font-weight value.

I had tried normal and 1000, but when I changed it to 600 the font anti-aliasing decreased and the faux bold was no more.

So to clarify, I use:

```
font-weight:600; /* Use in font-face declarations */
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* Use on text styles (p, h1, h2...) */
```

The top one fixes Firefox, the bottom fixes Safari.